# how to read the contents of a folder with a cursor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

i'm having a problem with read some image files that I copied in a folder in this path: /sdcard/DCIM/Wallpaper/.

The problem lies in the reading of these images randomly:

I'm using this method but it seems that the cursor is not reading the URI that i passed, what happened?

```
public static Uri getRandomImage(ContentResolver resolver) {

    String[] projection = new String[] {
        BaseColumns._ID
    };


    String folder = "/sdcard/DCIM/Wallpaper/";
    folder = folder + "%";
    String where = Media.DATA + " LIKE ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{folder};

    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        projection, where, whereArgs, MediaColumns._ID);


    if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
            return null;
    }

    cursor.moveToPosition(new Random().nextInt(cursor.getCount()));

    return Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, cursor.getString(0));
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: 
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:464)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:380)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView.getImageFromUri(TileView.java:562)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView.onDraw(TileView.java:241)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6741)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6744)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6744)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6744)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1842)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(4458):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the Uri for a directory, which will not be present in Media Uri. So you are getting FilenotfoundException.

You will have to make a custom query to get only images present in the directory

Edit:
Never tried, but do give it a try. the where clause should use LIKE. If this does not work you might have to look around to construct LIKE clause.

```
String folder = "/sdcard/DCIM/Wallpaper/";
folder = folder + "%";
String where = Media.DATA + " LIKE ?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[]{folder};

cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    projection, where, whereArgs, MediaColumns._ID);
```

Edit2:

In `getContentResolver` you are returning as null. `getContentResolver` is a method of Context. use `context.getContentResolver`

Comment: I edited my question with the code implemented with your advice, but still gives me error and I posted the logcat

Comment: i didnt realise you already had a contentresolver, use resolver instead of getcontentresolver

Comment: I edited my question with the code implemented with your advice, but still gives me error again